# Django 1.4 PBKDF2 Password Hash

Tags: django

Last few days I did a lot of research and test about how to implement PBKD2 in objective C.
Although I have found many viable answers, all tries give me another result than django 1.4.
I put some example that I tried to generate hashes.

As Key I was adding salt downloaded from the server (django format:
$$$), as data I added the same password I used to create django user. Unfortunately, my result hash string is completely different that this stored in Django database. Example function code:

```
NSData *hmacForKeyAndData(NSString *key, NSString *data)
{
const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [data cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
return [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
}
```

Could anyone give me a little advice, what is going wrong ?

Comment: Have you base64-decoded the salt?

Comment: Yeah, I had, but my decoding seems to not work properly as I test it. I'll try to fix it and try again.